# Files showing in smbclient but not smbmount

Tags: linux, samba, mount

I have a samba folder that I try and access through smbclient, and I can browse it just fine. However, mounting it through smbmount, all the folders under the share are empty. I can list the folders directly under the share fine, but they all appear empty.

smbclient:

```
# smbclient //server/share -U username -W workgroup password
```

smbmount

```
# sudo smbmount //server/share mntpoint -o user=username,workgroup=workgroup,password=password
```

I have also tried with domain=workgroup instead of workgroup, both give the same result. No error messages, everything mounts fine, but all the folders under mntpoint are empty, despite the same folders being non-empty when using smbclient.

Are these using different libraries? How can I debug the error?

Additionally, if I try to mount //server/share/folder, doing an ls results in a segmentation fault. Using dmesg I find:

```
kernel BUG at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.28/fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c:315!
```

Full trace: http://pastebin.com/m70adc213

Using a credentials file, I first get empty dirs, then Resource temporarily unavailable. In my dmesg I see the following output:

```
CIFS VFS: compose_mount_options: Failed to resolve server part of \\srv\share to IP: -11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a credentials file instead; see `smbmount(8)` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command :

mount -t smbfs -o username=username,password=password //server/shared_dir /mnt/

Comment: Per the manpage, mount -t smbfs calls smbmount -- so I wouldn't expect much difference.

Comment: The mount works fine without workgroup, now I get the following error trying to list folders: ls: cannot access share/folder/: Resource temporarily unavailable

Answer (score 0):

While the difference in between smbclient and mount.{cifs,smbfs} did seem to indicate that this is a client issue (well, it might still be), what solved something similar for me was to update my smbd to the latest released package from my distro.